# Neo4j - query issue for same label and one property the same

Tags: neo4j, nodes, label

I have a problem in querying for two nodes with one similar property, one different property and having the same label. For one property, the property is the same between both nodes, i.e. both have a property called `"Name"` and both have the same value (`"Data Storage"`). For the other property though called `"Note"`, they have different values. Both share the same label called `"Issue"`. When I use the query below, I get both nodes.

```
match (n:Issue) where n.name="Data Storage" return n;
```

However, when I query with the following query...

```
match (n:Issue) where n.name="Data Storage" and n.note="xxxx" return n;
```

...it only works for one of the nodes and not for the other. I've tried creating the node which doesn't query and it seems to work fine. But I also did it with a different label. Is this some bug around not being able to query a node having the same label and sharing at least one common property?

Comment: Neo version? Is it an upgraded store?

Comment: Note that property names are case sensitive, you stated initially that the properties are named 'Name' and 'Note' but in your query you use lowercase property-names ?

Answer (score 2):

```
match (n:Issue) where n.name="Data Storage" and n.note="xxxx" return n;
```

will match all nodes with label Issue, the value of the "name" property = "Data Storage" AND the value of the "note" property = "xxxx".

As you've described the 2 nodes, the value of the note property is different on each. The one matching xxxx is the only one that can be returned.
What is the goal of this query?

Answer (score 0):

If this was your real question.

**Query a node having the same label and sharing at least one common property?**

you can try this for each property and do a union over all

```
MATCH (n:Issue)
WITH n.name, collect(n) as nodes, count(*) as cnt
WHERE cnt > 1
RETURN nodes
```

or this will be less performant

```
MATCH (n:Issue)
WITH n
MATCH (m:Issue)
WHERE m<>n AND (n.name = m.name OR n.note = m.note)
RETURN n,m
```